# netsh.exe on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, netsh

For some reasons, I used command

```
netsh interfaces ip reset nul
```

On Windows 2003 Server it cleared all.
But on Windows 2008 Server it cleared only IP, mask and GW, but not DNS, WINS.
What am I doing wrong? How could I clear all on 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you try running these commands:

```
netsh winsock reset all
netsh int 6to4 reset all
netsh int ipv4 reset all
netsh int ipv6 reset all
netsh int httpstunnel reset all
netsh int isatap reset all
netsh int portproxy reset all
netsh int tcp reset all
netsh int teredo reset all
```

?